# React client socket not connecting with server socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

So im new to socket-io and react, im using express for backend. the version of socket.io-client im using is 3.0.3. and the version of socket-io package im using in the backend is 3.0.3 as well, the server connects to other requests given via raw html sockets but it is not connecting with react socket.io-client.

client Side:

```
import './App.css';
import {MainComponent} from "./Components/MainComponent"
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import openSocket from "socket.io-client";
const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:5000");


function App() {
  
  socket.on("chat", message => {
    console.log(message);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Router>
    <MainComponent></MainComponent>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server side:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Chats = require("./model")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/chats",{useNewUrlParser:true});
const db = mongoose.connection;

io.on("connection",(socket)=>{


    console.log("user has connected")
    io.emit("chat","hellow world");
    socket.on("join-room",(room)=>{
        Chats.find({},(err,data)=>{
            if(err) throw err; 
            socket.emit("load-messages",data)
        })
    })
    socket.on("message",(data)=>{
        socket.join(data.room);
        io.to(data.room).emit("serverMessage",{message:data.message,user:data.user})
        const newChat = new Chats({message:data.message,user:data.user,room:data.room})
        newChat.save();
    })
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"))



app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile("index.html")
})

app.get("/chats",(req,res)=>{
    Chats.find({},(err,data)=>{
        if(err) throw err; 
        res.json(data)
    })
})



http.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("the server is up and running in the port 5000")
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change 5th line in client side to below:

```
const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:5000", {transports: ['websocket']});
```

In server side change below line

```
io.emit("chat","hellow world");
```

to this

```
socket.emit("chat","hellow world");
```